# Error with texlive-publishers-doc. Cannot install it

Tags: 14.04, latex, texlive

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I install `texlive-full` from the repositories. It went all fine until the installation stopped with this error:

> Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-extra/texlive-publishers-doc_2013.20140215-2_all.deb **Size mismatch**

So I cannot install texlive-publishers where there are some packages I need to use to compile my work with LaTeX.

Any guess??

Comment: Can you try to manually fetch the file again from the URL given, copy it to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`  and then try again?

Comment: I tried to do so but my browser says "Gateway Anti-Virus Alert:
This request is blocked by the SonicWALL Gateway Anti-Virus Service. Name: Binder.BC_3 (Trojan)". Then I tried to download the package manually from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-publishers-doc/download.   But the download failed because of a network error"...

Comment: Your antivirus is the cause then, you'll have to disable it for apt to work or allow this URL to be accessible.